# jQuery-ui tooltip cannot set css font color

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, colors

I am using jQuery-UI v1.12.1 (jQuery 2.1.3) to dynamically create tooltips with HTML content. While I can get most of the HTML styling done using a CSS stylesheet, for some reason I am unable to change the font color of different classes without using !important.

**In case this has an easy answer: Is there an obvious reason why I would be able to change pretty much everything (e.g. background, font size, weight, etc) except the font color using the CSS "color" property?**

My code is embedded in a lot of other code that I cant post it here, nor do I know where to start to create a toy case that has the same problems. The best I know to do is record a little about the basic structure of my tooltip management. I have a CSS stylesheet with many classes defined, many of which have overlapping properties. In my javascript, I inject jQuery-UI and jQuery and use the following to create a tooltip based on the status of certain dividers' attributes and class names:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        content: function () {
            var html = do some stuff to determine html;
            return html;
        },
        classes: {'ui-tooltip': 'tooltip'}
    })
});
```

Each divider that has the 'tooltip' class gets a tooltip. In addition, the HTML in that divider may have multiple other classes associated with particular spans, divs, etc. All the CSS is defined in a single stylesheet. I am not using the jQuery-UI css.

The only way I can get colors to work is if I use !important, which I have read is bad practice. Otherwise, the font color is always gray.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not wrap your content with a `div` or a `span` that has a class that you can better manage via CSS?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Twisty. Everything is in divs and spans with their own class names. I think I'm running into some kind of priority issue, but I cant track it down. It's very strange to me that only the color attribute needs an !important to work.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net example that replicates this?

Comment: I can try, though my guess is that if I can actually replicate it, I'll have found the source of my problem, which is both the obvious way to an answer and the whole reason I have a question (because it's difficult to track down in my code and difficult to reproduce enough of the code to get the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Using a basic tooltip example, I have this working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/q9ay2w44/

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="#" title="That&apos;s what this widget is" data-tip-class="red">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native
  tooltip.
</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
  <a href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a> will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p>
  <label for="age">Your age:</label>
  <input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
</p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip div {
 display: inline-block; 
}

.red {
  color: #F00;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip({
    items: "[title]",
    content: function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var tipClass = element.data("tip-class") ? element.data("tip-class") : "black";
      var wrap = $("<div>", {
        class: tipClass
      });
      wrap.html(element.attr("title"));
      return wrap;
    },
    classes: {
      'ui-tooltip': 'tooltip'
    }
  })
});
```

If the font color is not changing for you, I suspect something else is styling the font after your tooltip. If you need more help, use this fiddle to try and explain or show the issue.

You'll notice I excluded the Jquery UI CSS as you mentioned. This has an adverse effect of showing some of the extra `div` and `span` elements that would normally be hidden.

Comment: Thanks very much for setting up this jsfiddle. I took your minimal code and used it to produce my own standalone html that produces tooltips of the variety I want. I could not reproduce the font color issue. I hadnt thought it relevant, but I am injecting code into existing websites to create the tooltips. This makes me think there's some styling in the website that I can only overwrite with the !important flag. Otherwise, I'm at a loss.